# Issue with game canvas resizing, using JavaScript and HTML 5

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

A few friends and I have been working on a web-based game over the last month or so, we have experience with programming but we are very new to web development. So this is a huge learning experience for us.

We followed this 'case study' in order to get our game area and canvas auto resizing: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/gopherwoord-studios-resizing-html5-games/#disqus_thread

We have managed to get it to work however we have encountered two problems and cannot identify the reason behind it.

Firstly, on any browser, if the height is changed the size of the game canvas/game area does not appear to change. Once the width has been adjusted however, it then resizes correctly.

Secondly, everything works as expected when opening it in Internet Explorer 11. IE 11 has a feature where you can emulate a previous version of the browser. When emulating IE 10, the width appears fine however the height is really small, making the game appear rather squished.

I have gone through the code, using alerts and drawing pictures on whiteboards yet I just cannot find where I have gone wrong.

Here is the code for the resize function:

```
    function ResizeGame()
    {
        // State the desired aspect ratio (the wanted width / the wanted height)
        var desiredHeight = 946;
        var desiredWidth = 1920;
        var desiredAspect = desiredWidth / desiredHeight;

        // Determine the new dimensions of the window & the new aspect ratio
        var newWidth;
        var newHeight;
        if (window.innerWidth != undefined)
        {
            newWidth = window.innerWidth;
            newHeight = window.innerHeight;
        }
        else
        {
            var docBody = document.body;
            var doc = document.documentElement;
            newWidth = Math.max(doc.clientWidth, docBody.clientWidth);
            newHeight = Math.max(doc.clientHeight, docBody.clientHeight);
        }
        var newAspectRatio = newWidth / newHeight;

        // Determine whether the new aspect ratio has gone out of sync and correct it
        if (newAspectRatio > desiredAspect)
        {
            newWidth = newHeight * desiredAspect;
            gameArea.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
            gameArea.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
        }
        else
        {
            newHeight = newWidth / desiredAspect;
            gameArea.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
            gameArea.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
        }

        // Move the window to the top left - allows for the window to be centralised later if we want
        gameArea.style.marginTop = 0 + 'px';
        gameArea.style.marginLeft = 0 + 'px';

        // Apply the changes the canvas as well
        gameCanvas.width = newWidth;
        gameCanvas.height = newHeight;

        // Determine the new global scale
        var desiredSize = desiredHeight + desiredWidth;
        var newSize = newWidth + newHeight;
        scale = newSize / desiredSize;

        // Update distance from the side which the canvas starts
        elemLeft = gameCanvas.offsetLeft;
        elemTop  = gameCanvas.offsetTop;

        // Scale down the message box title and message
        messageBoxTitle.style.top = 210 * scale + 'px';
        messageBoxTitle.style.left = 450 * scale + 'px';
        messageBoxTitle.style.width = 820 * scale + 'px';
        messageBoxTitle.style.fontSize = (newWidth / 400) + 'em';

        messageBoxMessage.style.top = 350 * scale + 'px';
        messageBoxMessage.style.left = 450 * scale + 'px';
        messageBoxMessage.style.width = 820 * scale + 'px';
        messageBoxMessage.style.fontSize = (newWidth / 720) + 'em';

        // Append changes
        document.body.appendChild(gameCanvas);
    }
```

The CSS for the game area and game canvas:

```
    #GameArea
        { 
            position: absolute;
            left; 0px;
            top: 0px;
        }

        #GameCanvas
        { 
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

The HTML for the game area and canvas:

```
    <div id="GameArea">
        <canvas id="GameCanvas">Canvas not supported in your browser.</canvas>
    </div>
```

I hope I have provided all the information that is needed. Thank you very much for your time.

Kyle

Comment: Not sure if it will make a difference but you're appending the body on every resize, this will clutter the DOM fast! Try `document.body.removeChild(gameCanvas);` before `document.body.appendChild(gameCanvas);`

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I shall make the change asap :)